# Cant import android HDMI package even though it is in master

Tags: java, android, hdmi-cec

I am trying to use `HdmiCecMessage` class in my android app, so I installed this dependency in my gradlef file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.hardware:hardware-hdmi:1.0.0'
}
```

but when I try to import:

```
import android.hardware.hdmi.HdmiCecMessage;
```

I get an error I get an error `"cannot find symbol HdmiCecMessage"`.
I saw in google open source that it exsists:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/9302a73/core/java/android/hardware/hdmi/

any ideas?
thanks

Comment: `android.hardware.hdmi.HdmiCecMessage` is not part of the Android SDK, either as a framework class or through a library. There are no classes from `android.hardware.hdmi` in the Android SDK. That class is part of the OS implementation.

Comment: @CommonsWare is there a way to send HDMI CEC commands through an android app? using https://source.android.com/docs/devices/tv/hdmi-cec somehow? the android HDMI-CEC control service

Comment: I have no idea, sorry.